# Проверка заполнения полей в форме и отправка сообщения на e-mail

Tags: php

Есть несколько форм и все практически разные, но обработчик один. Как можно организовать проверку, если поле заполнено, то и данное значение поле отправляется на почту. Если не заполнено, то вовсе не отправляется.

Вот кусок самого обработчика

```html
<?php
....
/*ЗДЕСЬ ПРОВЕРЯЕМ ЕСЛИ ХОТЯ БЫ ОДНО ИЗ ПОЛЕЙ НЕ ЗАПОЛНЕНО МЫ ВОЗВРАЩАЕМ СООБЩЕНИЕ*/
if($name=="" or $phone==""){
    echo "Заполните все поля";
}

else{
    /*ЕСЛИ ВСЕ ПОЛЯ ЗАПОЛНЕНЫ НАЧИНАЕМ СОБИРАТЬ ДАННЫЕ ДЛЯ ОТПРАВКИ*/
    $to = "iphonevalera21@yandex.ru"; /* Адрес, куда отправляем письма*/
    $subject = "".$tema."" /*Тема письма*/;
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: <iphonevalera21@yandex.ru>\r\n";/*ОТ КОГО*/

    /*ВО ВНУТРЬ ПЕРЕМЕННОЙ $message ЗАПИСЫВАЕМ ДАННЫЕ ИЗ ПОЛЕЙ */
    $message .= "Имя: ".$name."<br>";
 $message .= "Телефон: ".$phone."<br>";
 $message .= "Почта: ".$email."<br>"; 
 $message .= "Вопрос: ".$vopros."<br>";
 $message .= "Наименование товара: ".$item_name."<br>";
 $message .= "ID товара: ".$item_id."<br>";
 $message .= "Артикул: ".$item_article."<br>";

    /*ДЛЯ ОТЛАДКИ ВЫ МОЖЕТЕ ПРОВЕРИТЬ ПРАВИЛЬНО ЛИ ЗАПИСАЛИCM ДАННЫЕ ИЗ ПОЛЕЙ*/
    //print_r($message);

    $send = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

    /*ЕСЛИ ПИСЬМО ОТПРАВЛЕНО УСПЕШНО ВЫВОДИМ СООБЩЕНИЕ*/
    if ($send == "true")
    {
        echo "<p style='color: green;'>Ваше сообщение отправлено. Мы ответим вам в ближайшее время.\r\n</p>";
    }
    /*ЕСЛИ ПИСЬМО НЕ УДАЛОСЬ ОТПРАВИТЬ ВЫВОДИМ СООБЩЕНИЕ ОБ ОШИБКЕ*/
    else
    {
        echo "<p style='color: red;'>Не удалось отправить, попробуйте снова!</p>";
....
}?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$message .= (isset($name)) ? "Имя: " . $name . "<br>" : '';
$message .= (isset($phone)) ? "Телефон: " . $phone . "<br>" : '';
и т.д.
```